# Treat folders as file

Tags: windows, operating-system, directory

Compressing a folder into a .zip file is a common way to treat a folder as file, for example, uploading a folder. Is there a faster way to "pack" the contents of a folder into a file (without taking the time to compress)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a tarfile.  In unix or mac, its the tar command.  On Windows there is a tool called 7-zip.

You can see more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)).